# Selenium executeScript is not returning List<WebElements>

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Selenium executeScript is not returning List. The following code is trying to write something to the subject field of an email, save it as a draft and then search for the draft through the search field.

```
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('NewMessage').click();");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('fSubject').value = \""+ test +"\" ;");
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('SaveDraft').click();");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('c_clogot').click();");
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
              "var f = new FocusEvent('focus');"
            + "var m = new MouseEvent('click');"
            + "var q = document.getElementsByName('query')[0];"
            + "var b = document.getElementsByClassName('c_search_go c_search_psb_go')[0];"
            + "q.dispatchEvent(f);"
            + "q.dispatchEvent(m);"
            + "q.value =  \""+ test +"\" ;"
            + "b.dispatchEvent(m);");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
```

The following javascript is getting all elements with class 'Fmd', but the JavaScriptExecutor is not returning the list of WebElements.

```
    String scriptToExec = "return document.getElementsByClassName('FmD');";
    List<WebElement> resultsList = (List<WebElement>) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript(scriptToExec);
```

Comment: So what does it return? An instance of which class? Do you get any exception on the Java side? Do you get any JS exception on the browser side? Which browser are you using? Did you try in another one? Did you try creating a simple page with a few elements and no other functionality and using `document.getElementsByClassName()` there?

Comment: It doesn't return any thing. No exception either. I am using firefox. I was looking for the number of elements with class 'Fmd', if it more 2 or more. So to get it working i did this `String scriptToExec = "var r = document.getElementsByClassName('FmD'); if(r.length>2 || r.length == 0){return false;}else{return true;};";
Boolean isValid = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(scriptToExec);`

Comment: You should post this as an answer, and the accept it.